# iOS browsers not able to login - Azure AD

Tags: ios, azure, adal

We have an angular js application that using Azure AD for authentication. We used adal.js and adal-angular.js libraries to integrate Azure AD with our application.

Azure AD login is working on android mobiles but its not working on iOS mobiles and goes into infinite loop with any browser on iOS mobiles.

Also Azure login is not working on desktop machines with safari browser.

I have done a enough research on this not found useful information to fix this.

Please share suggestions if anybody who has faced this issue before and having solution for this.